# PHP calculate combinations of a string depends on a character string

Tags: php, math

This is the scenario:

There is characterstring like this:

```
$characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
```

And I have a method that generates a random string with a variable length depends on the characters variable:

```
public function generateCodes($length, $qty)
    {
        $codes = [];

        if ($length > 0 && $qty > 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $qty; $i++) {
                $code = '';
                for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                    $code .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];

                    if (!in_array($code, $codes)) {
                        $codes[] = $code;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What I want is to calculate the possible unique codes for a specific $length. But how can I reach this?

This is my attempt so far - but I do not consider something important.

```
public function calculateCombinations($length)
    {
        $combinations = 0;

        if ($length > 0) {

            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $combinations = $combinations + pow(2, $length -1);
            }
        }

        return $combinations;
    }
```

What is the right formula for this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you just want the possible no of unique codes it will be n! but  if you are trying to get possible yah you can it will break the system

Comment: Each letter can be one of 36 choices so you'll have 36^l possible combinations (where l is the length). Now if you want all possible combinations with length less than l then it's (Sum_i^l 36^i)

Comment: This is more a math problem than a programming problem. You should learn something about combination -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: yes i Know That its a Math Problem and hope here is someone who can push me into the right Direction

Comment: So what's wrong with apokryfos suggestion? If it is wrong, could you provide an example of numbers you want to get for some small `length` such as 3?